# In Version 6, tried to get french alphabates in collection but getting special characters

Tags: blueprism

We recently migrated from a Windows 7 environment running Blue Prism version 5 to a Windows 10 one running Blue Prism version 6.

The issue arises when we get an Excel Workbook with French language-specific characters as a Blue Prism Collection.

In the Windows 7/Blue Prism v5 resource environment it works as expected. However in the Windows 10/Blue Prism v6 one in place of the French alphabet characters we are getting a "?" character.

Comment: I think that the Excel Action "Get worksheet as Collection" uses the Copy to Clipboard method to get the data from excel to BluePrism. Could you try to copy the excel range with french letters and paste it to the notepad? Do french letters copy there?

Answer (score 0):

This is *probably* an issue with your Blue Prism 6.x language pack, but could be a .NET language issue.

I suspect it's working with the Windows 7 environment because the Blue Prism 5.x resource has French language/localization support, while your Blue Prism 6.x resource running in the Windows 10 environment does not.

If it were an issue with your OS environment you would see the characters incorrectly displayed in Excel as well. Since it sounds like the issue is only in the Blue Prism collection itself then.

**That being said** if you find that your Blue Prism 6.x language settings are configured to correctly support of French characters I would check that your Windows 10 version of .NET has French language support as well. This stems from the way Blue Prism uses the `DataTable` .NET class from the `DataSet` object in the `System.Data` namespace to construct and transmit Collections.

Eitherway, and given how janky the BP Excel VBO is, I highly recommend looking at how the Blue Prism Excel VBO converts an Excel Worksheet range into a Blue Prism Collection.